# Store View issue magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

Hi Magento Experts,

I've some issue in my Magento Store. When i am creating or editing any attribute it is showing bunch of spanish title for attribute title but in store view there no such stores available. Please help me to remove all these spanish input boxes.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some database relationship issue so i deleted stores from database manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can view below setting in bottom left side in  magento for admin locale and make changes according your preference.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No, It has no effect. Still i am facing the same issue. Basically i want to delete all extra input boxes because i did not created and need them.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System > Manage stores` and see if you have any unwanted storeviews. It is also possible to delete them here.